# Skip line instead of hiding in SSRS Report writer

Tags: reporting-services

I know how to hide a line in SSRS report, but I want to skip line, instead of printing blank line. Why I need it: I am creating report for a customers with account number and SSN number. In case there are multiple accounts with the same SSN - I want to print SSN total amount. In case one account with single SSN I don't need to print a total line. Hiding a total line put a lot of blank lines. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: can you show what you mean with picture and datasets

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution how to skip (not to print an empty line) instead of hiding it.
Right click on a line you don't want to print with certain condition, select "Row Visibility" and enter expression in "Show or hide based on expression".

[image: Here is the picture how to do it]